# html's input type="file" dialog box seems to hide certain files when in c:\windows\system32

Tags: html, windows, google-chrome, firefox

The following issue occurs in Chrome and Firefox and maybe other browsers too.

I'll give the info so you can reproduce it

Suppose I have some HTML

It's just this line really, that is the issue

```
<input multiple="" type="file">
```

Here's all of it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<input multiple="" type="file">
</body>
</html>
```

I am in Windows 7

I tried creating an administrative command prompt and creating a file there

called a.a

I did another called aa.exe earlier

```
C:\Windows\System32>copy con a.a
sdf^Z
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\Windows\System32>dir a.a
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is B411-D580

 Directory of C:\Windows\System32

06/09/2015  02:07 AM                 3 a.a
               1 File(s)              3 bytes
               0 Dir(s)   4,005,048,320 bytes free

C:\Windows\System32>
```

Then I go to the webpage and click to bring up the standard upload screen

I have tried this in FF or Chrome, same issue.

[image]

Notice that a.a and aa.exe  aren't showing in the web browser file browsing dialog box, but are in cmd

They show in windows 7 explorer window

And in case it makes any difference, they are not hidden (H attribute is not set)

```
C:\Windows\System32>attrib a.a
A            C:\Windows\System32\a.a

C:\Windows\System32>attrib aa.exe
A            C:\Windows\System32\aa.exe

C:\Windows\System32>
```

So I don't see why my web browsers' file browsing dialog box is hiding them.

Notice that the dialog box is selected to show all files. And I tried typing * into the box but still it didn't show those files a.a and aa.exe

I'm interested in what rule it is using to decide what to hide And if it is documented. And if there's any direct way around it. ( besides moving said exe to another directory and opening it there)

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just some (filesystem) cache? I.e., did you try right-clicking in the file chooser, and clicking "Refresh"?

Comment: this could be a size issue, that it isn't finding them because they are so small; have you tried it with larger files?

Comment: @RachelGallen  no, I can sort by size and see 0kb and 1kb.. You can try it

Comment: @Siguza  refreshing doesn't cause it to appear. You can try it, and you'd see. I made the question so it's easy to see how to reproduce it

Comment: [Except it works for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPi60.png). I wouldn't be asking for clarification if I was able to test it myself.